# Restriction on path(s) which can be accessed from Cloud Endpoint portal by specific users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints

Trying to restrict certain user from accessing specific paths defined in swagger file. Using IAM roles there is way to restrict a user by giving specific access to one specific Endpoint (providing access to only roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer & roles/servicemanagement.serviceController for that particular endpoint), but not able to find a way to restrict a user to access on specific path of that endpoint.

For example:
Our cloud Endpoint swagger definition contains 3 path ('/path1', '/path2', '/path3'). The requirement is to have user1 only access and see definition of only '/path1' but not others, and user2 should be able to and see definition of '/path2' & '/path3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible in Cloud Endpoints.

If you really need this functionality I would suggest you to [create a Feature Request in Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187193&template=0), that way the GCP team will know you are interested on the functionality and maybe implement it in the future.

Comment: Yes, i will create a support ticket for it. Thankyou for your input!

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting/upvoting this answer so that the community can see that you've been sufficiently helped.